# set value to the td using class name in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, html-table, sendkeys

My td contains

```
<tbody id="gridview-1161-body">
 <tr id="gridview-1161-record-19832230" data-boundview="gridview-1161" data-recordid="19832230" data-recordindex="2" class="x-grid-row x-grid-data-row" tabindex="-1">

#supplier item
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1154" id="ext-gen2524">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>xxx/div></td>
#id
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1156" id="ext-gen2526">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>yy</div></td>
#cost
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1157" id="ext-gen2527">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field"></div>$15.00</div></td>

#qty - **here i want to set value 10** id is dynamically generating
<td role="gridcell" class="x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell" id="ext-gen2528">
<div class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:right;">
<div class="rp-invalid-cell rp-icon-alert-require-field" id="ext-gen2632"></div>&nbsp;</div></td>

</tr><tbody>
```

**i want to click this td and set value as 10 then click enter**.I have tried.

```
e=driver.find_element_by_class_name('x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp- 
grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable-cell').send_keys('10')   
e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

and

```
e=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid- 
cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell  rp-grid-editable- 
cell']")
e.send_keys("10")
```

but im getting

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
>   selector","selector":".x-grid-cell x-grid-td
>   x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158  rp-grid-editable-cell 
>   rp-grid-editable-cell"}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
e = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.x-grid-cell-headerId-gridcolumn-1158.rp-grid-editable-cell.rp-grid-editable-cell')
e.send_keys('10')
e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Plus, i think that this kind of error **NoSuchElementException** appears when Selenium is unable to find your element. The reasons may be:

- Your driver.find_element has the wrong parameters, but considering your code, it seems unlikely.
- The element you try to find is not displayed. You should consider using the wait:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, time).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, class_name)))
  ```

Comment: when you run your test, is the <td> element displayed when this part of your code is supposed to be running ?

Answer (score 0):

To click the `<td>` element, set value as **10** then to `click()` <kbd>Enter</kbd> you have to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.x-grid-cell.x-grid-td.rp-grid-editable-cell[role='gridcell']")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  element.send_keys('10')
  element.(Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@role='gridcell' and contains(@class, 'rp-grid-editable-cell')]")))
  element.click()
  element.clear()
  element.send_keys('10')
  element.(Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
  ```

Comment: i have created more td but "gridcolumn-1158" this thing only unique in class name.

Comment: In that case you need to provide more of the outerHTML so the element can be uniquely identified.

Comment: I still don't find any unique attribute for this `<tr>` tag. Maybe some more of the outerHTML would help.

Comment: once it is click then throwing "raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable" at line element.send_keys('10')

Comment: Can you update the question with the HTML of the actual `<tbody>` tag?